# Does Application.CaptureScreenshot() leak memory? (iOS)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, screenshot

I have created a simple application for iphone with one button from UI that executes just one line of code when I click on it. This is the code:

```
public void CaptureScreenShot()
    {

        Application.CaptureScreenshot ("Screenshot.png");

    }
```

After I capture one screenshot, the memory increases by about 10 MB then drops only 7 MB

http://postimg.org/image/6r5tiaqjv/

When I take second screenshot, it goes up 7 MB, but doesn't drop at all, until I flip the device, and only then it goes to the starting amout of memory + 3 MB

http://postimg.org/image/am4m74kbv/

And then, if I want to take 2 screenshots in the row, it goes up like +25 MB of starting memory and drops 2 MB after a little period of time

http://postimg.org/image/5yyk5cwyz/

And even if I flip the device, it goes like 2 MB lower, but it is like +20 MB of the memory I use when I start the device. The point is, after taking at least one screenshot, I will never get the memory back. (The memory I had in the start)

Then I decided to try capture a screenshot manually with this code:

```
public void TakeScreen()
    {
         // Timestamp returns the date, so each screenshot name would be unique
        string pngFile = Application.persistentDataPath+"/+Timestamp+".png";
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height);
        texture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);
        texture.Apply();
        byte[] bytes = texture.EncodeToPNG();
        File.WriteAllBytes(pngFile,bytes);      
        DestroyObject( texture );
    }
```

Same thing happens with memory usage as with Application.CaptureScreenshot();
Could someone explain, what am I doing wrong, or is there a way to avoid this memory leak?
I have the same problem when I try to save a picture from WebCamTexture():

```
public void TakeSnap ()
    {
        // Timestamp returns the date, so each screenshot name would be unique
            string pngFile = Application.persistentDataPath+"/+Timestamp+".png";
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(wct.width, wct.height);
        texture.SetPixels32(wct.GetPixels32());
        texture.Apply ();
        var bytes = texture.EncodeToPNG();
        File.WriteAllBytes( pngFile,bytes);     
        DestroyObject( texture );

}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't have a Mac but anyway, I tried your code in Windows and it worked without any leak (as it should). Maybe there is an internal texture format conversion that causes some leak. Let's try to specify texture format by hand. Something like `new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false, false)`. Other than that, I think it's a Unity bug and you will have more luck by reporting it to Unity developers.

Comment: It only happens with iphone... With Windows it works fine

Comment: As C#/.NET is using garbage collection, you may be better off, triggering a (or multiple) "GC.Collect()" before taking a memory sample.
Which Unity version do you use?

Comment: I use Unity 5.0.0f4 and "GC.Collect()" didn't help at all. I tried it before, and today once again